# How to rename all files and folder containing underscore to hyphen in Linux

Tags: linux, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I want to rename all files and folder containing underscore in name and replace underscore with hyphen.

Currently I am using following code,

`rename '_' '-' */*/*`

It was working but now it is showing me "Argument list too long"

Comment: The command probably matches too many files names, so that their name's expansion grows to long, at least longer then the maximum size of a shell's command.

Comment: How can we make to work in a loop? I will be very thankful it someone can help me here!

Comment: You might like to take a look at the awk tool. Or use the find command with its option `-exec`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$ tree foo
foo
├── dir_1
│   └── foo_file_2
└── file_1

1 directory, 2 files
$ for ft in d f; do find foo -type $ft -execdir sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0//_/-}"' {} \; ; done 2>/dev/null
$ tree foo
foo
├── dir-1
│   └── foo-file-2
└── file-1

1 directory, 2 files
```

This renames all directories and then all files (the `for` loop over `d f`) because I haven't been able to make it do all renaming in one iteration.